PhpSpreadsheet Date Export Issue 1900/1904
I'm trying to generate a downloadable Excel file that includes Excel dates generated from PHP timestamps. The issue is that Excel for Windows and Mac use two different base dates which are also covered in PhpSpreadsheet.
/** PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\Date */
const CALENDAR_WINDOWS_1900 = 1900; //    Base date of 1st Jan 1900 = 1.0
const CALENDAR_MAC_1904 = 1904; //    Base date of 2nd Jan 1904 = 1.0

When setting CALENDAR_WINDOWS_1900 the dates are wrong on Macbook and vice-versa. My idea was to use JavaScript to detect if the users is on Macbook or Windows and then choose the corresponding base date when creating the Excel file.
Is there any better solution for this ?
Thanks !

How are you setting the dates in cells?

I would rather use a user agent parser PHP library than javascript, but I guess both methods are somewhat inaccurate.
However, AFAIK Excel for Mac uses 1904 base date only up to the 2008 version, and users might open your file with e.g. LibreOffice, so knowing the OS alone might not be enough.
As I see PhpSpreadsheet writes the date mode to the Xlsx, so Excel should be able to open the dates correctly - but I don't have Excel to check this.
the best you can do might be to inform your users about this issue - this is not your fault after all, but an unfortunate design decision in Excel.
